# Add and Calculate Fields of Iterated Annotation Classes

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, error-999999, calculate-values

I'm have difficulty with my script **Arcmap v10.5.1**.  I get a syntax error on line 8.  My question is:  Can I calculate the Added field from an existing field within an iterated value?  If so, what's my syntax error preventing me from doing so.  If not, how should I proceed?  **my workspace is a feature dataset**

```
import arcpy, os, sys

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    arcpy.AddMessage("Adding fields and updating " + fc + "...")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fc, "KM_FontSize", "DOUBLE")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "KM_FontSize", "!FontSize!")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fc, "KM_VerAlign", "SHORT")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "KM_VerAlign", "!VerAlign!")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fc, "KM_HorAlign", "SHORT")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "M_HorAlign", "!HorAlign!")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fc, "KM_XOffset", "DOUBLE")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "KM_XOffset", "!XOffset!")
    arcpy.AddFieldmanagement (fc, "KM_YOffset", "DOUBLE")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "KM_YOffset", "!YOffset!")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Finished updating " + fc + "...")
```

And here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python Scripts\KM_Utility\Create Anno Fields.py", line 10, in <module>
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "KM_FontSize", "!FontSize!")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3661, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Syntax error
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

Comment: Default language is VB and you are providing the field name enclosed with !! which is python syntax. Try: `arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "KM_FontSize", "!FontSize!", "PYTHON")`

Comment: Thank you.  I was reading the syntax for Pro.  FYI>  in Pro the default is Python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BERA mentioned in comments, you need to specify `PYTHON` as your expression type. The default is `VB`.

`arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "KM_FontSize", "!FontSize!", "PYTHON")`